# Call a function in code behind without using javascript

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i am calling a function on onclick, onmousemove and onkeypress event in form tag and the function is in code behind but the method is not executing when user clicking, pressing a key and moving mouse on form1. The code is :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onclick="idletime()" onkeypress="idletime()" onmousemove="idletime()">
```

.cs file :

```
protected void idletime(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("hello.");
}
```

Comment: Two problems here: 1. you are using JavaScript: that is what you using in those event handlers attribute (`onclick`…). 2. You cannot directly call server side (C#) code from JavaScript: everything has to go through an HTTP request (if not using a helper library – which I would recommend – you need to script `XmlHttpRequest` to call dedicated entry points on your server.

Comment: can u explain it through code.

Comment: Not easily within the scope of a [SO] question (and WinForms makes it more complex for me: but does have its own approaches). Look for WinForms AJAX tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to do that. I am writing down some rough sample code. Hope it may help.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onclick="idletime()" onkeypress="idletime()" onmousemove="idletime()">



<script>

function idletime() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "demo.aspx/functionName1",
                data: "{parameter1:'" + param1 "',parameter2:'" + param2 + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                   alert(msg.d);
                }
            });
        }


</script>
```

c# code

```
using System.Web.Services; --- use this class

   [WebMethod]
        public static string functionName1(string parameter1, string parameter2)
        {

            ------------------------------;
            return "Demo";
        }
```

Comment: i have tried that, but how can i access variables and methods declared outside this method.

Comment: You can declare variables and methods as static, that you want to use with webservices. as webservice is declared as static.